# Quanteda merging unigrams and bigrams

Tags: text-mining, quanteda

I want to experiment if having both unigrams and bigrams in one DFM improves my document classification. I would like to create both unigrams and bigrams in one DFM. From there, I can then get my TF-IDF weighted DFM considering both unigrams and bigrams. Possibly, I can possibly create unigram and bigram dfms separately and then I can merge them. But, I would like to know if quanteda has a more efficient way of doing this. I appreciate your responses.

Comment: Got it from the quanteda page. It works with something like this. 

`toks_skip <- tokens_ngrams(toks, n = 1:2)`

Comment: Exactly, that's the solution.

Comment: Please consider posting this as an answer (and accept it), so that it may be useful for others in the future (comments may get deleted at any time).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it from the quanteda page. It works with something like this.

```
toks_skip <- tokens_ngrams(toks, n = 1:2)
```